# How to install NLTK in Ubuntu Apache Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, nltk

I have Apache Hadoop 1.0.0 installed on ubuntu machine. Now i want to install Natural Language ToolKit (NLTK). How to install NLTK in Hadoop node ? Can anyone help me with steps to install it.

Any help is greatly appreciated !!!